# Error using mongodb with java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB to store data. In my project I am connecting multiple users(100-2000 users) to a server using thread pool and store the responses of those users in the database. But when I do this I am getting this error. Please help me with this. I am not able to get it. I have already wasted 45 hours on this error.

**Error:**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.CommandExecutor.executeCommands(CommandExecutor.java:129)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.CommandExecutor.run(CommandExecutor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mongodb.DBPortPool$SemaphoresOut: Out of semaphores to get db connection
    at com.mongodb.DBPortPool.get(DBPortPool.java:176)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:370)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:149)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:102)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.objects.LoginRequest.storeData(LoginRequest.java:152)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.LoginHandler.handleRequest(LoginHandler.java:20)
    ... 8 more
com.mongodb.DBPortPool$SemaphoresOut: Out of semaphores to get db connection
    at com.mongodb.DBPortPool.get(DBPortPool.java:176)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:370)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:212)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:160)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:183)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.drop(DBCollection.java:777)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.drop(DBApiLayer.java:206)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.CommandExecutor.executeCommands(CommandExecutor.java:118)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.CommandExecutor.run(CommandExecutor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Have you checked the MongoDB source code, especially for the `DBPortPool` class?

Comment: I just have the jar file of that.. In which DBPortPool class is present... How can I read that java source..

Comment: You download the source from the MongoDB website: http://www.mongodb.org/downloads (the rightmost column)

Comment: The source is available at github: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing the number of connections in the connection pool.

Look [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.4/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html#connectionsPerHost), at the connectionsPerHost.

Comment: This may be the right way to solve it. There's also the [threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.4/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html#threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier) which may be relevant. But maybe shalki have found and tried these already after a week of troubleshooting?

Comment: yes.. I tried that also. It was not working by increasing this. The same error occurs.

Comment: If you set connectionsPerHost to a value as large as your thread pool, you should never get the error that you're getting now.