# MongoDB with Spring Data - Out of semaphores to get db connection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

> `
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Out of semaphores to get db connection; nested exception is com.mongodb.DBPortPool$
>   SemaphoresOut: Out of semaphores to get db connection
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:70)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1538)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:370)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:730)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:633)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:589)

What is fix for this?
`

Answer (score 2):

you're not closing connections properly.  either close it in a try/finally around your insert call or if your connection is injected, make sure it's scoped to, say, a request and close it when that scope ends.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081450/error-using-mongodb-with-java)?
There is a configuration option to increase connections, described [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.4/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html#connectionsPerHost).

Also, I recommend reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520439/how-to-configure-mongodb-java-driver-mongooptions-for-production-use) to learn how to properly configure it.

From the last question linked:

> **threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier**. Number of threads that are allowed to wait for connections to become available if the
>   pool is currently exhausted. This is the setting that will cause the
>   "com.mongodb.DBPortPool$SemaphoresOut: Out of semaphores to get db
>   connection" exception. It will throw this exception once this thread
>   queue exceeds the threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier value.
>
> If you expect big peaks in throughput that could cause large queues
>   temporarily increase this value. We have it at 1500 at the moment for
>   exactly that reason. If your query load consistently outpaces the
>   server you should just improve your hardware/scaling situation
>   accordingly.